# How to implement multiple regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am practicing simple regression models as an intro to machine learning. I have reviewed a few sample models for multiple regression, which is, I believe, an extension of linear regression, but with more than 1 feature. From the examples I have seen, the syntax is the same for linear regression and multiple regression. I get this error when running the code below:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size.
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\****\Desktop\data.csv")

#x.shape =(20640, 2), y=(20640,)
X = df[['total_rooms', 'median_income']]
y = df['median_house_value']

X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=0)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Am I missing a step? Thanks for your time.

Comment: So, should I guess you are a fellow fan of Thomas Pynchon? :)

Comment: I am. Hoping for a final novel soon.

Comment: Cool. Did the answer resolve your issue?

Comment: I believe so, but I need to do some data cleaning, which may have been my initial problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your `train_test_split` - the order of results matters; the correct usage is:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=0)
```

Check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to do anything you don't want to do :-). But generally speaking, you're going to want to handle things like multi-collinearity somehow -- but that doesn't necessarily mean dimensionality reduction.

What's the shape of your data? If you have, say 20 features, but 10k observations, there should be no need for dimensionality reduction (at least not in a first pass).

But if you have, say, 1k features and 10k observations, then you'd be well suited for a unsupervised dimensionality reduction step before the learner.

You might want to first try some regularization (see https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/ -- you can download the book for free from there).

So for instance, try using the `ElasticNet` class instead of the `LinearRegression` class. It's pretty much the same thing, but with a penalty on the $L_1$ and $L_2$ norms of the weights. This tends to help with generalization.

Without know much more about your particular problem, it's difficult to say anything else.